# Trying to import multiple CSV files into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I recently downloaded and installed MongoDB Compass Community.  I am fiddling around with this technology now.  I am trying to figure out an easy way to import multiple CSV files in one folder into MongoDB.  I can easily import one single CSV at a time, but I can't get a bunch imported all in one shot.  I saw a video on YouTube, and they guy used NoSQLBooster for MongoDB to import multiple CSV files into Mongo.  It worked fine in the video that I saw.  Using NoSQLBooster for MongoDB, I clicked on Import > Mongoimportutility > Select the folder that I want to import multiple files from...now I see this.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this before?  Is there something not configured correctly or setup correctly?  It seems like this should be a pretty straightforward thing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoSQLBooster depends on the command line utilities provided by MongoDB.  You will need to get them from the MongoDB [download center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community) and install them on the machine where you will run NoSQLBooster.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.  I just figured out how it works.  You gotta click Options > change/Set Bin Path for MongoDB Utilities > OK.

[image]

After I did that, it worked!!